# Can I use input (file) to select a video AND load it’s corresponding json (with same root name)?

Tags: json, file, input, html5-video, createobjecturl

I have a project with two files:

- example.mp4
- example.json

These files are in the same path. I need to select only the `example.mp4` file and automatically load the corresponding `example.json` file automatically.

I’m not sure if the `window.URL.createObjectURL` will identify the final directory etc..

Many Thanks.

Comment: I suspect this is not possible due to web security..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.